# Laravel: verify if the email has been signed in before the system allows the user to signout

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

How can I verify if the email was signed in before the system allows the user to sign out?

```
public function signoutUser(Request $request)
{
    if (User::attempt(['email' => $email])) 
    {
        return redirect()->intended('profile');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with auth()->check().

```
if(auth()->check()){
    auth()->logout();
}
```